# Clearing the cache from a button in a webapp

Tags: javascript, html, caching, sencha-touch

Last week I had a problem with my webapp. Normally we have two versions per week and sometimes it´s necessary clear the cache and the system to detect a new version and install itself after. I have two options:

- Is it possible create a button with the option "get latest version"? and fire and event clearing the cache
- Add this lines in the header html:

  ```
  <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
  <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
  <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
  ```

But the second one I don´t know if it´s enough to solve the problem.

What is the best option in your opinion??

Comment: the one of the best way i feel is, keep create your version folder on each release and add tour all the resource in the version-folder. i.e **version-1.2.3**/ja/script.js

Comment: I don´t know how implement your way in my app or I don´t understand your response.. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just wanting to clear the cache of static assets such as CSS and JavaScript you could add a version to their requests if you are using a server side language such as PHP. So for example:

```
<script src="/scripts/my-js-file.js?v=1"></script>
```

Then when you click a button, post a form to the same page and increment that version.

That is one solution. There are a few others.

Comment: Thanks Alex Rogings but the backend is not PHP, I am wanting other solution. Thanks

Comment: To fetch the latest version on demand of the user, you would need to be using a server side language I believe.

Comment: Yes, backend side is running with SAP

Comment: ASP or SAP? Not aware of SAP

Comment: SAP @alexrogins the perfect way would be: click in a button and reload the app and clear the cache automatically. But I don´t know how to..

Comment: Could a solution be to not cache the app at all so the client is always seeing the latest version? Or do you actually want them to see the old version of the app sometimes (for some strange reason)?

Comment: perfect way it would be... with a button can be able to get the latest version, imagine if you have 2.9 version and you want to force the new version (2.9.1 for instance) reload the app and install the new version.

Comment: In that case, then using a server side language is the only way I know how as it needs to be aware that there is a newer version.